# how to save a an entity which has a foreign key to User in django rest framework?

Tags: django, authentication, serialization, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

In my django rest framework project, i have a model names Profile and which has a forignkey for the User(to store the third party variables like address etc.).

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other user data
    title = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    contact_number = models.TextField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

What i need to know in how to to write the serializer class and View to create the profile. When the a new user removes from the app, the associated profile should be deleted too. 
**Problem**: how to write the serializer class and view to create profile.

Comment: why don't you just extend user model and add these extra fields to user model itself?

Comment: yes. But i need to keep profile details in a separate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do like this(in this code, the user information is taken directly from `request.user` which is the logged in user):

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

and use [generic view](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) to create the Profile:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class UserList(generics.CreateAPIView):
    model = Profile
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But once i call the end point it gives following exception :IntegrityError at /auth/users/profile/create
NOT NULL constraint failed: Users_profile.user_id

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it. Simplest one is, add User fields to Profile serializer one by one, using **source** mappings;

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email')
    password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password', write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('title', 'contact_number', 'description', 'location', 'username', 'email', 'password')

    def create(self, data):
        user_data = data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user, **data)
        return profile
```

Another option would be to create a serializer class for User, and make use of writable nested serializers. This way, you can dp the validation and creation of User instances in its own serializer, and use this serializer inside ProfileSerializer.

In either approach, you do not need to change anything on the view side, all this logic would be handled in the serializers.

As for deletions, as you defined ForeignKey relation with **on_delete=models.CASCADE**, if you delete a User instance, associated Profile instance will be deleted. But you need to write a custom delete method if you want to do this other way around (delete a user when associated profile is deleted). But if you want such tight coupling between a User and Profile, the better way would be to extend the User class to have your custom user model, as Aarif suggested.